# How do I stop people on my wifi from being able to see my computer?

Tags: networking, windows-8, file-sharing

I'm on Windows 8.1. I never noticed this before but when you open file explorer and then click network, my own computer shows up there. If you click on it, you can see "users" and click that then you can click my user then they can get onto my computer.

I thought that was something to do with rdp but I disabled that and it still pops up. So I thought it was homegroup but I'm not in a homegroup. I tried google but I cant find anything else. How do I turn it off?

I thought it was network discovery too but that only turns it off for my pc. How do I know that someone on another computer cant see my pc?

Comment: Network discovery **off** on your PC stops anybody else seeing your computer. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### "When you open file explorer and then click network, my own computer shows up there"

This is called [Network Discovery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7).

---

#### When Network Discovery is turned On

> This state allows your computer to see other network computers and devices and allows people on other network computers to see your computer. This makes it easier to share files and printers.

Source [What is network discovery?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7)

---

#### When Network Discovery is turned Off

> This state prevents your computer from seeing other network computers and devices and prevents people on other network computers from seeing your computer.

Source [What is network discovery?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7)

---

#### **To turn off Network Discovery**

> 1. Open Advanced sharing settings
>
>    - Click the Start button
>    - Click Control Panel
>    - In the search box, type network, click Network and Sharing Center
>    - In the left pane, click Change advanced sharing settings.
> 2. Click the chevron to expand your current network profile.
> 3. Click Turn off network discovery
>
>    [image]
> 4. Click Save changes.
>
> If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type
>   the password or provide confirmation.

Source [Enable or disable network discovery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-disable-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7)

---

#### Advanced Sharing Settings

The advanced sharing settings page also allows you to explicitly turn off:

- File and printer sharing
- Public folder sharing

> [image]

---

Comment: Does turning off network discovery actually disable file sharing though?  Based on the description it would seem, what actually happens is that, Windows stops trying to locate other installations that have file sharing turned on.  I read the description again, and it does seem to imply that, Windows would also not be discoverable on the network.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm note completely sure either. There is a seperate File and Printer sharing toggle on the same page but I think is independant, ie you can have discovery on and sharing off. If you have discovery off and file sharing on then I think discovery overrides file sharing. I don't have a network here to test it on :/

Comment: I thought I would bring it up.  I just know in the past I have left network discover enabled, but disabled file sharing, which allows me to access those files on computers that do have file sharing on but won't allow those computers to access the other machine.

Comment: @Ramhound That sounds right to me ;)